# How to detect change in HTML page after a successful redirect from form?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
class ChangePasswordView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = ChangePasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
```

login.html

```
 {% if XXXXXX %}
     <p style="color:green;">Password changed successfully! Please login.</p>
 {% endif %}
```

Basically I want the following message to appear on my login html page if password was changed. Is there a way to detect if form was successful (by passing some parameter to HTML), or if user was redirected from certain URL to current html page?

Comment: You could do this by using the django messages module. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/ you could also return a query parameter in the URL and then check for the query inside of the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing a specific message, it might be easier to work with [Django's *message framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).

You can use the [**`MessageSuccessMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin) to add a message to the session, so:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin


class ChangePasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = ChangePasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    success_message = 'Password changed successfully! Please login.'
```

Usually on all pages you then write logic to report messages to the user, as [specified in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages):

> ```
> {% if messages %}
> <ul class="messages">
>     {% for message in messages %}
>     <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
>     {% endfor %}
> </ul>
> {% endif %}
> ```

In case there are messages, that page will deliver these to the user, and remove these from the session to prevent showing these a second time. It is thus a way to add messages that will (later) be reported to the user when they visit the next page.